# Data structure for callback matrix implementation in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, callback

I am looking for the data structure that would be good for the implementation of a decision matrix with arguments of a non-POD type on the one hand and callback functions on the other hand.

Particularly I would like to use some kind of the one-to-one correspondence between the *set/tuple* of the arguments and the callback function. In this case **presence of a particular set of argument values ​​would lead to an unambiguous definition of the callback**, something like that:

```
template<typename t1, typename t2, ...>
(t1 arg1 == _1_1, t2 arg2 == _2_1, t3 arg3 == _3_1) -> void callback_func_1()
(t1 arg1 == _1_2, t2 arg2 == _2_2, t3 arg3 == _3_2) -> void callback_func_2()
(t1 arg1 == _1_3, t2 arg2 == _2_3, t3 arg3 == _3_3) -> void callback_func_3()
...
(t1 arg1 == _1_n, t2 arg2 == _2_n, t3 arg3 == _3_n) -> void callback_func_n^3()
```

There should be a search method that will select the callback function that corresponds to the set of arguments with values equal to the given values (in the terms of C++-like pseudocode):

```
template<typename t1, typename t2, ...>
void CallbackMatrix::SelectCallback(t1& arg1, t2& arg2, t3& arg3, ...)
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(const auto& item, Matrix)
    {
        if( arg1 == item.arg1 && arg2 == item.arg2 && ... )
        {
             item.function();
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

From my point of view this data structure could be useful for many developers, so I am looking for library implementation of the one (may be, somewhere in Boost?). Although I'll be grateful if someone offers his own version of this data structure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for seems complicated to me. Are you sure you cannot redesign your program to avoid this?

Anyway, let's consider your non-POD type to be the class `MyType`

```
struct MyType
{
  int         i;
  double      d;
  std::string s;

  MyType(...) {...} //ctor
  bool operator<( const MyType& other) //define a 'lexicographical' order
  {
    if(      i < other.i 
        || ( i == other.i && d < other.d )
        || ( i == other.i && d == other.d && s.compare( other.s ) < 0 ) )
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
};
```

Then, instead of callbacks, let's use a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

```
class MyFunc
{
public:
  virtual void function( MyType& ) = 0;
  virtual ~MyFunc() = default;
};

class FirstImpl : public MyFunc
{
public:
  void function( MyType& t ) {...} // do something
};

class SecondImpl : public MyFunc
{
public:
  void function( MyType& t ) {...} // do something else
};
```

Finally, use a map where keys are of MyType (and this is why we need to overload the operator < in MyType) and values are (pointers to) MyFunc derived objects.

```
std::map<MyType, MyFunc*> Matrix;
//feed you map
MyType t1( 42, 0., "hey" );
MyType t2( 7, 12.34, "cool" );
MyFunc *f1 = new FirstImpl;
MyFunc *f2 = new SecondImpl;
Matrix.insert( std::make_pair<MyType, MyFunc*>( t1, f1 ) ); // can also use the C++11 map::emplace
Matrix.insert( std::make_pair<MyType, MyFunc*>( t2, f2 ) );
```

Then, you can call your select function

```
template<typename t1, typename t2, ...>
void CallbackMatrix::SelectCallback(t1& i, t2& d, t3& s, ...)
{
    for_each(const auto& item : Matrix)
    {
        if( i == item.first.i && d == item.first.d && ... )
        {
             item.second->function( item.first );
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

Does this solution fit you?

### Edit - second solution

**Caution: the following is pseudo-code**; I didn't try to compile it! But the idea is here.

We still need a `MyType` class to overload the operator <. Notice that `MyType` becomes a POD. Is it a problem?

```
struct MyType
{
  std::vector< boost::any > myVec;

  bool operator<( const MyType& other)
  {
    if( myVec.size() != other.myVec.size() )
      return false;
    else
    {
      for( int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i )
      {
        if( myVec[i] < other.myVec[i] ) // so types must be comparable
          return true;
        else if( myVec[i] > other.myVec[i] )
          return false;
      }

      return false; // meaning myVec and other.myVec are identical
    }
  }
};
```

Then, SelectCallback becomes

```
void CallbackMatrix::SelectCallback( std::vector< boost::any > args )
{
  for_each(const auto& item : Matrix)
    if( args.size() == item.first.myVec.size() )
    {
      auto mismatch_pairs = std::mismatch( args.begin(), 
                                           args.end(), 
                                           item.first.myVec.begin() );

      if( mismatch_pairs.empty() ) // if no mismatch
      {
           item.second->function( item.first );
           break;
      }
    }
}
```

Of course, filling MyType objects with data will be slightly different, like

```
MyType t1;
t1.myVec.push_back( 42 );
t1.myVec.push_back( 0. );
t1.myVec.push_back( static_cast<char const *>("hey") );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I learned a lot from them (especially the strategy pattern). But honestly I need a little more abstract solution (possibly based on variadic templates?) that would provide an opportunity to build and operate the `std::map` (mentioned in your answer) with any level of `MyType` complexity (== any number of dimensions).

Comment: @VitalyIsaev Ok, I propose a second solution. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you, your second solution is clear for me (so I will award the bounty as soon as site will allow me to do that). The only thing I still can't figure is why are you wrapping the callbacks into the classes, what do we gain from this?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev Well, I guess it is a matter of style. If I should implement your problem, I will do this way. But you can indeed use generic callback as map values, using C++11 std::function + std::bind or boost::function + boost::bind.